# Why can't Clang optimise away std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization

Why can't Clang 3.6 generate the same assembly for versions `a` and `b` of the following program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << std::max(3, argc) << std::endl; // a
    //std::cout << std::max({3, argc}) << std::endl; // b

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `-O3`, the relevant bits of assembly for `a` and `b` respectively are:

```
##a
    cmpl    $2, %edi
    movl    $3, %esi
    cmovgl  %edi, %esi
    movq    __ZNSt3__14coutE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi

##b
    movq    ___stack_chk_guard@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r15
    movq    (%r15), %r15
    movq    %r15, -32(%rbp)
    leaq    -40(%rbp), %rcx
    movl    $3, -40(%rbp)
    leaq    -36(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edi, -36(%rbp)
    movl    $3, %esi
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %r8
    movq    %rcx, %rdx
    jmp LBB0_1
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB0_2:
    movl    (%rbx), %edi
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movq    %rbx, %rax
LBB0_1:
    cmpl    %edi, %esi
    cmovlq  %rax, %rdx
    movq    %rcx, %rbx
    addq    $8, %rbx
    cmpq    %r8, %rbx
    movl    (%rdx), %esi
    jne LBB0_2
    movq    __ZNSt3__14coutE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi
```

From my limited knowledge of assembly, it looks like version `b` has compiled to a `std::max_element` algorithm, which is clearly less efficient than the algorithm used in `a`. Why is this? What sort of optimisations can we realistically expect when using `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: You use 2 different functions, and code for `std::initializer_list` has to work for any size.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'd still expect the same output here; this to be a poor algorithm for a small number of elements, which I suspect is the normal use-case for the `std::initializer_list` version of `std::max`.

Comment: Why ask such a question on S.O.?  Clearly there's no conceptual issue around correctness, so it's just a matter of whether it's been noticed and prioritorised by the clang authors - they must have a website where you can ask them about it....

Comment: @TonyD Because I'm curious if there is a good reason why this can't be optimised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upgrade your clang to a later version, as someone obviously has spotted this inefficiency and improved it:

This is the code generated by your `b` example now:

```
movl    %edi, %eax
movl    $3, (%rsp)
movl    %eax, 4(%rsp)
cmpl    $3, %eax
cmovlel (%rsp), %eax
```

It's not quite as neat as your original example, but it's better than the code generated by your 3.6 compiler.

As always, what optimisations a compiler does is highly dependant on "what the authors have spotted and found a fix for". First step is "make it work". Then you look at making it faster/smaller.

My clang version:

```
clang version 3.7.0 
(http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 490122a3730b4ac7120ba9bee3e5dc51510d68d9) 
(http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 1c63fe6c61b2e1d6050f971f26946cda1e708a9c)
```

Comment: Great! Hopefully they have made a similar optimisation for a 3-element list which I suspect is most used case.

Comment: Yes, three arguments also gets inlined - although as I made it two constants and argc, I felt that it could be a bit cleverer and remove the number three from the equation by knowing 5 is greater already. But I guess that's a stupid case anyway, and time is better spent on optimising less "you shouldn't write that silly code anyway".,